# Element width 100% of PAGE (not browser window)

Tags: css, width

**Edit:** For the sake of simplicity, I reduced my problem with overlay (see Background below) to width of a div. By doing that I however created a different and somewhat artificial problem. The accepted answer solves my real problem. The "reduced" problem is not solved there.

How can I make div with width equal to 100% of the page width? (without setting fixed `min-width`)

Seemingly, the solution is trivial. `<div>` with its 100% width should be OK by itself. That works fine unless you shrink the browser window below the page width (that's when scroll bars appear). Then the width of the `<div>` element is equal to the window size, not to the page size.

A note on the demonstration code: The first div simulates the page width. The divs below are my attempts to achieve an element wide across all page. If the page is big enough (more than 500px), they are rendered as expected - all over the page. But if you shrink the window (below 500px) and scroll bar appears, then the divs also shrink, although I want them to stay at 500px.

Here's the code, or check it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32mcsxbk/) if you prefer

```css
/* just to see sizes of the elements */
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* this simulates the width of the actual page content */
div#fixed {
  width: 500px;
}
    
div#full1 {
  width: 100%;
}

div#full2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

div#full3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* this works fine, but uses fixed size min-width, I cannot use */
div#fullOK {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">Width fixed to 500px</div>
The DIVs below are attempts to achieving 100% width despite scrolling. All work only if the window is wider than 500px.
<div>default</div>
<div id="full1">just width 100%</div>
<div id="full2">width and min-width 100%</div>
<div id="full3">run out of ideas</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="fullOK">fixed min-width is the only thing that works (unusable for me though)</div>
```

Background: I have a page, which has an editor area that can be resized by the user. It has a    modal dialog windows support, which - when invoked - shows a window and covers the rest of the page by a semi-opaque background with height and width set to 100%. It works well, unless it is viewed in window smaller than the page. Then scrolling shows part of the page not covered by the background, which looks ugly. I need to have this background spanning all over the page, not just over the visible area. Setting `min-width` and `min-height` could be done only with the help of JavaScript (due to unknown page size, as the user can resize the canvas) and I'd prefer avoiding that.

Comment: first can you share some code so we can help second thing scroll appears only when there is something of fixed width or height other wise window will shrink with it

Comment: if you remove div with fixed width or min-width then http://jsfiddle.net/32mcsxbk/3/ it is what you want?

Comment: @himanshu No. The first div simulates the width of the page. Isn't that obvious from the description? You are supposed to work on the other divs, so that they span across whole page.

Comment: then set min-width equal to biggest div width you are using other than that i dont know any other way

Comment: Please share the code here - that way it is preserved for future visitors to SO in the event the linked source goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position: fixed` for the overlay. The scrolling doesn't matter as elements that are fixed will position themselves in relation to the viewport. `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` will keep the overlay over the entire page no matter what you do.

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning) (emphasis mine):

> fixed
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and **don't move it when scrolled.** [...]

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
body {
  background: white;
}
.cover {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
<h1>I am overlapped!</h1>
<input type="text" value="cant touch this" />
```

Comment: The overlay works! But now I don't know how to proceed :) I had a problem with overlay, which for simplicity sake I reduced to div width problem. I believed these problems are equal. However your solution solves my overlay problem, but it doesn't solve the reduced - seemingly equal problem. Pragmatic view is to accept it as it solved my problem, SO view is to keep it unanswered, so the future reader has a chance to find answer to div problem.

Comment: OK, if there is another big problem you should post it as another question :) The primary focus of this question was the overlay and scrolling, which is fixed.

Comment: Yes, it's been caused by my wrong reduction. I thought I was simplifying something, instead I was creating something different. You answered my real problem, although whole question is about the reduced problem :) Sorry about all this confusion. Good thing is that it works!